# Bootstrap - Carousel with images centered and auto-resized in width and height based on the Div container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to implement a carousel with Bootstrap, where the images are centered and auto-resized. For example, in the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/koba1/mb94dgzu/6/), as you can see the first image (the vertical one) stretches the whole div, while the third image remains at the top. I would like to reproduce the behavior of the Facebook or Twitter carousel, where the images are positioned in the center and resized according to the Div where they are included. Can you help me?

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
<!-- Indicators -->
<ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active">One</li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1">Two</li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2">Three</li>
</ul>

<!-- Inner -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://scontent.ffco3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435-9/171147625_1208393786271117_8898528403586821491_n.jpg?_nc_cat=111&ccb=1-3&_nc_sid=730e14&_nc_ohc=dDKFCCAYB-oAX_m2xtu&_nc_ht=scontent.ffco3-1.fna&oh=aa418a1e5facad55e6e4781237602778&oe=609A1892" 
             class="img-responsive" />
        <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>Photo 1 - Vertical</h1>
                <p>Hello!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://scontent.ffco3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435-9/173646266_1210629629380866_4626783539462302067_n.jpg?_nc_cat=111&ccb=1-3&_nc_sid=730e14&_nc_ohc=QelU_ZVtqAcAX9wHI-l&_nc_ht=scontent.ffco3-1.fna&oh=272c997f1febf514a031aefe9cb712cb&oe=609BBCA2" 
             class="img-responsive" />
        <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>Photo 2 - Square</h1>
                <p>Hello again!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://scontent.ffco3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435-9/167432599_1203101340133695_8518788973824059736_n.png?_nc_cat=107&ccb=1-3&_nc_sid=730e14&_nc_ohc=CItpIApuYmgAX_zHj8t&_nc_ht=scontent.ffco3-1.fna&oh=83145492bb38c8c2148df70086382459&oe=609A928F" 
             class="img-responsive" />
        <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>Photo 3 - Horizontal</h1>
                <p>Hello again and again!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Controls --> 
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="icon-prev"></span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="icon-next"></span>
</a> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
.carousel-indicators > li, .carousel-indicators > li.active {
    width: 100px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: solid 1px grey;
    background: lightgrey;
    text-indent: 0;
}
.carousel-indicators > li.active {
    background: white;
}

#myCarousel {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
$('#myCarousel').owlCarousel({
    autoHeight:true
});
```

Remove Height on CSS

```
#myCarousel {
  width: 400px;
  /*height: 400px;*/ /*remove This*/
}
```

Updated Code

```
#myCarousel .img-responsive{
  margin:0 auto;
  max-height:400px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/qnrzuhm2/

Updeted :- https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/xmy46z3L/1/

Comment: Thank yo Lalji for the answer, but I still se the first image not-resized. Also the third is still not centered.

Comment: @Koba Answer Updated

Comment: Thank you Lalji Tadhani, now the first photo seems to work, but the second and the third I suppose they should be centered (don't know if you have in mind the Facebook\Twitter carousel)